# Salesforce User unable to run on click javascript button that launches flow but administrator can

Tags: apex, javascript

Hello guys I have a button that is suppose to allow the user clicking it to take ownership of a record. When I run it as admin, all else works but as a standard user nothing happens:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js")}

if ("{!Job_Requisition__c.owned__c}" != true) {
    alert('Job Requisition must be owned before any tasks can be checked. Please take ownership of the Job Requisition first.');
} else {
if ("{!Job_Requisition__c.updatedJobRequisitionTasks__c}" != true) {
    var url = encodeURI('/flow/Job_Requisition_Tasks?JobRequisitionId={!Job_Requisition__c.id__c}&retURL=/{!Job_Requisition__c.url__c}');

window.location.replace(url);
} else {
    alert('Job Requisition Tasks have already been checked');
}
}
```

What permission do I have to change on the profile to allow them to run this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **System Permission - Run Flows** setting is the likely culprit.